# Function within directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry to ask for suck seemingly easy question, but I really don't know how to handle it and I can't make it work.
 I have this directive which recieves data from a $broadcast, which then has to use to create a new template.

```
  app.directive('emptyScope', function() {
    return function( $scope ) {
       return $scope.$on('checkEmptyArray', function(event, data) {
          return {
            template: '<img src="../images/apple.png">'
          };
      });
    }
});
```

The data from 'checkEmptyArray' comes in perfectly, and through console.log I can see that indeed, it recieved the data.
But for some reason, it doesn't do the

```
return  {
            template: '<img src="../images/apple.png">'
          };
```

I don't understand why it isn't doing it.
Does someone have any clue? Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use that directive?

Comment: Probably another [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), but the question isn't clear enough to be sure.

Comment: yeah sorry, i wanted to render a new <img> tag, that's all

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything because it's a callback. You'll need to render your image within your function.

```
app.directive('emptyScope', function() {
    return function( $scope ) {
       return $scope.$on('checkEmptyArray', function(event, data) {
          $scope.myImg = data;
      });
    }
});


 <div ng-bind-html="myImg"></div>
```